# Запуск java файла после компиляции

Tags: java

Почему после в консоли после компиляции java файла.
1)Командой javac Helloworld.java происходит компиляция все хорошо. Появился файл с расширением .class (байт код)
2) Хочу запустить программу по логике вещей нужно запускать
java Helloworld.class, но у меня требует именно java Helloworld
Почему именно так? и при запуске данной команды, какие файлы он подхватывает?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/

Answer (score 0):

Потому что программа `java` ожидает получить в качестве своего параметра название класса, а не файла, в котором байткод этого класса находится. Если вы используете Java 11, вы можете запускать свою программу сразу `java Helloworld.java`, то есть без предварительной компиляции в class файл. При этом `Helloworld.class`, в той же директории, не должно быть, иначе не запустится.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вторую часть вопроса -- "какие файлы он подхватывает" (не очень ясно, правда, что такое "подхватывает"). Виртуальная машина (`java.exe`) ищет класс, имя которого передано в параметре, в текущей директории и в директориях, перечисленных в параметре командной строки `-jar`, в системной переменной `CLASSPATH`, и/или в директориях, перечисленных в параметре `-cp` (`-classpath`). Напр.

```
  java -cp ./bin com.my.package.MyClass    
  java -jar myJar.jar
```

При этом подразумевается, что в директории `/bin` есть поддиректория `com/my/package`, в которой лежит откомпилированный файл `MyClass.class`, а в файле `myJar.jar` есть поддиректория с именем `META-INF`, в которой лежит файл, называемый `MANIFEST.FM`, в котром есть строка вида

```
Main-Class: com.my.package.MyClass
```

(это указание виртуальной машине, какой класс из архива надо запускать) а в директории `com/my/package` лежит сам класс, `MyClass.class`, содержащий точку входа (`public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`).
Подробней см. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html (там, правда, не очень внятно объясняется)